# How do i get the the combinations from the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table with 61 records, where the first are "atomic" identified with their ID, and the other ones are combinations of the first 19 records like this

```
id  pi1 pi2 pi3
1    1
2    2
3    3
  ...
19   19
20   1  13
21   1  18
  ...
24   2  6
25   2  7
26   2  7   16
```

in a webpage i have a form where the user clicks in the buttons that correspond to the atomic records (e.g. choice 2 and 7). when the user submits, the backend should consider that the user pressed 2 and 7 and then the resulting set should be:

```
id
2
7
25
```

the 24th row shouldn't be on the result because the user didn't pressed it

to get the basic records, i think this should suffice

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id = 2
OR id = 7
```

if more options are pressed, the query would have more operators. but to access the complex combinations i don't know how to achieve it without getting unwanted records just because one of the options is present in one of the Pi's (pi1, pi2 or pi3)

Comment: Can you change your table design? There seems to be something terrible wrong.

Comment: @juergen d unfortunately no... this records are used in a many-to-many table where the other side are records that require mostly 3 combinations (1 atomic and other complex)

Comment: So do you mean you can't change it because the design is fix or you don't know how or don't want to? If you can change it at all you might consider doing it.

Comment: this design went ahead, because the original table built by a peer of mine had this columns
`id || description                       || opt1 || opt 2|| ... || opt 19`
`1  || op1 and opt 2 and opt 19|| 1      || 1      ||.... || 1`


but then i had to insert X and (A or B or C or D or E) [ this are the most complex] and that wasn't good to insert as one record, so i simplified the table

Answer (score 0):

It is really better to change your data structure to have a junction table -- one row per "new" id and one per related id.  However, you have the three columns.

I think this is the logic you want:

```
select t.*
from table t
where id in (2, 7) or
      (2 in (pi1, pi2, pi3) and
       7 in (pi1, pi2, pi3)
      );
```

However, this will give you id 26 as well.  Excluding that requires a bit more work.  In MySQL, this should do the trick:

```
select t.*
from table t
where id in (2, 7) or
      ((2 in (pi1, pi2, pi3)) +
       (7 in (pi1, pi2, pi3))
      ) = ((pi1 is not null) + (pi2 is not null) + (pi3 is not null))
```

Comment: meanwhile i got a workaround that is capable of doing what i want without changing the table structure, involving a temporary table... but i still have a little situation joining the two tables... if you could take a look [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237247/one-simple-join-is-not-enough-but-another-one-doesnt-output-what-i-want)

Comment: @tiagomagalhaes . . . This answer doesn't require changing the data structure.  That is just a suggestion that might make subsequent queries easier.