# One simple join is not enough but another one doesn't output what i want

Tags: mysql

i have a table with some "rules" for na app stored in it

```
id,pi1,pi2,pi3
"1","1",,
"2","2",,
"3","3",,
"4","4",,
"5","5",,
"6","6",,
"7","7",,
"8","8",,
"9","9",,
"10","10",,
"11","11",,
"12","12",,
"13","13",,
"14","14",,
"15","15",,
"16","16",,
"17","17",,
"18","18",,
"19","19",,
"20","1","13",
"21","1","18",
"22","2","3",
"23","2","4",
"24","2","6",
"25","2","7",
"26","2","7","16"
"27","2","7","19"
"28","2","16",
"29","2","17",
"30","2","18",
"31","2","19",
"32","3","10",
"33","3","12",
"34","3","16",
"35","4","16",
"36","4","19",
"37","5","18",
"38","6","11",
"39","6","13",
"40","6","18",
"41","6","19",
"42","7","16",
"43","7","18",
"44","7","19",
"45","8","13",
"46","8","18",
"47","9","11",
"48","9","16",
"49","9","18",
"50","9","19",
"51","10","12",
"52","10","16",
"53","11","13",
"54","11","18",
"55","12","18",
"56","13","16",
"57","13","18",
"58","16","18",
"59","17","18",
"60","18","19",
"61","4","18",
```

and the other one is generated on the go with all the possible combinations from a defined set of numbers (e.g. this one i selected 2, 7, 16, 17, 18, 19), and this was the output

```
idPI,pi1,pi2,pi3
"1","2",,
"2","7",,
"3","16",,
"4","17",,
"5","18",,
"6","19",,
"7","2","7",
"8","2","16",
"9","2","17",
"10","2","18",
"11","2","19",
"12","7","16",
"13","7","17",
"14","7","18",
"15","7","19",
"16","16","17",
"17","16","18",
"18","16","19",
"19","17","18",
"20","17","19",
"21","18","19",
"22","2","7","16"
"23","2","7","17"
"24","2","7","18"
"25","2","7","19"
"26","2","16","17"
"27","2","16","18"
"28","2","16","19"
"29","2","17","18"
"30","2","17","19"
"31","2","18","19"
"32","7","16","17"
"33","7","16","18"
"34","7","16","19"
"35","7","17","18"
"36","7","17","19"
"37","7","18","19"
"38","16","17","18"
"39","16","17","19"
"40","16","18","19"
"41","17","18","19"
```

And i want to inner join the two tables using only pi1, pi2, pi3 columns. i got into this

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.pi1, table1.pi2, table1.pi3, 
FROM db.table1
inner JOIN db.table2 c1
ON db.table1.pi1 = c1.pi1
```

with the following result

```
pi1,pi2,pi3,
2,,,
7,,,
16,,,
17,,,
18,,,
19,,,
2,3,, //this wrong shouldn't be here
2,4,, //this wrong shouldn't be here
2,6,, //this wrong shouldn't be here
2,7,,
2,7,16,
2,7,19,
2,16,,
2,17,,
2,18,,
2,19,,
7,16,,
7,18,,
7,19,,
16,18,,
17,18,,
18,19,,
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join these two tables using pi1,pi2,pi3 columns as keys then that's what you need to specify in your INNER JOIN ... ON statement as follows:

```
SELECT t1.pi1, t1.pi2, t1.pi3
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.pi1 = t2.pi AND t1.pi2 = t2.pi2 AND t1.pi3 = t2.pi3;
```

Comment: But then I'll only have the rows where the 3 columns are defined... I thought on having a join for each column and then join it all but with no result yet